# How do you remove duplicates from a three dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I'm having some problems with what code to write that will allow me to remove duplicates from a three dimensional list by using a list comprehension? Here is my list below and example.

`df = [[[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 17, 28],[7, 25, 27, 28],  [7, 17, 21, 27, 28]],[[3, 4, 28],[4, 7, 28],[4, 7, 28],[3, 4, 28],[4, 7, 14, 28],[3, 14, 28],[3, 4, 28],[3, 7, 14, 28]],[[7, 11, 28],[3, 11, 28],[3, 7, 12, 28],[7, 11, 12, 28],[3, 11, 12, 28],[7, 25, 27, 28],[3, 7, 11, 28]]]`

I would like my results to be:

`df1 = [[[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 17, 28],[7, 25, 27, 28],[7, 17, 21, 27, 28]],[[3, 4, 28],[4, 7, 28],[4, 7, 14, 28],[3, 14, 28],[3, 7, 14, 28]],[[7, 11, 28],[3, 11, 28],[3, 7, 12, 28],[7, 11, 12, 28],[3, 11, 12, 28],[3, 7, 11, 28]]]`

Comment: Why do you need it to be a list comprehension? It will be very ineficient as you will have to iterate the df list multiple times to search if it is the first appearance before inserting it. If you use a set to store already inserted elements and you use normal loops you will get a more efficient solution.

Comment: What about `[3, 7, 11, 28]`? List comprehensions exist to simplify work. But in this case I think they would do more harm than good, as the code would look very complex.

Comment: Side-comment: if `[3, 7, 9, 28]` represents something, they should probably be some kind of custom objects and not lists. A `class` with `__slots__` should be efficient memory-wise. You can provide the class with iteration functionality if you need them to be iterable for other parts of your code. Using lists, tuples and dicts to store everything smells to me.

Comment: So how do i get this to work if it can't be done with a list comprehension

Comment: I have given you the answer to the same.

Comment: Is there a way to make it into a two dimensional list then remove the duplicates?

Comment: you can use the 'chain.from_iterable' function from the itertools module.

Comment: Sorry i am kind of new to python and don't know how to used chain.from_iterable

Comment: So if you convert a 3d list to a 2d list, you actually flatten out your list into a 2d space. By that I mean, that you will now compare your lists into a wider space. That means, you will have a lesser lists in your final result. Try using new_df = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df)) and check out the results. After which, instead of using the for dflist in df part of the code below, directly use the new itertools df instead of dflist in the below code.

Comment: Convert into a 2d works but can you remove the duplicates from the 2d list . For example, 'df1 = [[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 17, 28],[7, 25, 27, 28],[7, 17, 21, 27, 28],[3, 4, 28],[4, 7, 28],[4, 7, 14, 28],[3, 14, 28],[3, 7, 14, 28],[7, 11, 28],[3, 11, 28],[3, 7, 12, 28],[7, 11, 12, 28],[3, 11, 12, 28],[3, 7, 11, 28]]'

Comment: Never mind . I figure it out. I can use your method and something like this to remove the duplicates.          result = [] for x in new_df: if x not in result: result.append(x) print (result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid such a mess by checking whether the list already exists before inserting it. This way you can avoid complicated loops.

EDIT : I know this is not what you directly wanted, but a list comprehension isn't required in my opinion. Easier to just go ahead and do the following:

EDIT2 : Added the sorted version as requested. Use the index positions of each 2d list as the key and sort them using the .sort() functionality of a list.

```
res = []
for dflist in df:
    df_set = set(tuple(y) for y in dflist)
    innerlist = [list(x) for x in df_set]
    innerlist.sort(key = lambda x: dflist.index(x))
    res.append(innerlist)
```

Comment: This is good enough and understandable but how to you sort the innerlist

Comment: Added the same bit in EDIT2

Comment: @CyrusDsouza what would I do without you?